# Python MySQLdb select from and insert into another database

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I have a table looks like this:

```
part    min    max    unitPrice
A       1      9      10
A       10     99     5
B       1      9      11
B       10     99     6
...
```

I also have a production table that I need to insert the previous data into this production one. 
When I do the select statement from one table and fetch the record, I have a hard time insert into another table.

Say

```
cursor_table1.execute('select part, min, max, unitPrice, now() from table1')
for row in cursor_table1.fetchall():
    part, min, max, unitPrice, now = row
    print part, min, max, unitPrice, now
```

The result turns out to be

```
'416570S39677N1043', 1L, 24L, 48.5, datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 8, 16, 33, 42)
```

I know Python smartly figured out the type of every column but I actually just want the raw content. So I can do something like this:

```
cursor_table1.execute('select part, min, max, unitPrice, now() from table1')
for row in cursor_table1.fetchall():
    cursor_table2.execute('insert into table2 values ' + str(tuple(row)))
```

The question is how can simply do a select statement from one table and add it to another.

Let me know if I did not describe my question in a clear way and I can add extra info if you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wanted all of the data to pass through Python, you could do the following:

```
import datetime

cursor_table1.execute('SELECT part, min, max, unitPrice, NOW() from table1')
for row in cursor_table1.fetchall():
    part, min, max, unitPrice, now = row
    cursor_table2.execute("INSERT INTO table2 VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,'%s')" % (part, min, max, unitPrice, now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') ))
```

Answer (score 8):

It might be a bit late to answer this question, but I also had the same problem and landed in this page. Now, I happen to have found a different answer and figured that it might be helpful to share it with others who have the same problem.

I have two mysql servers, one on Raspberry Pi and another on a VPS and I had to sync data between these two by reading data on RPi and inserting into the VPS. I've done it the usual way by writing a loop and catching the records one by one and inserting them and it was really slow, it took about 2 minutes for 2000 datasets.

Now I solved this problem by using the `executemany` function. As for the data I obtained all tuples returned by the `select` using the `fetchall` function.

```
rows = x.fetchall()
y.executemany("insert into table2 (f1, f2, f3) values (%s,%s,%s);", rows)
```

And it was super fast , it took about 2 seconds for 5000 records.

Comment: close to perfect, but `insert` statement **shoud not** be terminated with  semicolon `;`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to make any calculation with the data selected from table1 and you are only inserting the data into the other table, then you can rely on `mysql` and run an [`insert ... select`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html) statement. So the query code would be like this:

```
cursor_table1.execute('insert into table2 (part, min, max, unitPrice, date) select part, min, max, unitPrice, now() from table1')
```

EDIT:
After knowing that the tables are in different servers, I would suggest to use [executemany](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#some-examples) method to insert the data, as it would run faster.

First build a list of tuples containing all the data to be inserted and then run the `executemany` query

Comment: the problem is that they are not in the same server.. table1 and table2 cannot see eachother..

Answer (score 0):

I expect that several answers here will give you trouble if you have more data than you do memory.

Maybe this doesn't count as solving the problem in python, but I do this:

```
from sh import bash

# ... omitted argparse and table listing ...

for table_name in tables_to_sync:

    dump = 'mysqldump -h{host} -u{user} -p{password} {db} {table} '.format(
            host=args.remote_host,
            user=args.remote_user,
            password=args.remote_password,
            db=args.remote_database,
            table=table_name,
            )

    flags = '--no-create-info --lock-tables=false --set-gtid-purged=OFF '

    condition = '--where=\'id > {begin} and id <= {end}\' > {table}.sql '.format(
            begin=begin,
            end=end,
            table=table_name
            )

    bash(['-c', dump + flags + condition])


    load = 'mysql -u{user} -p{password} {db} < {table}.sql'.format(
            user=args.local_user,
            password=args.local_password,
            db=args.local_database,
            table=table_name
            )

    bash(['-c', load])
```

If you're worried about performance, you might consider cutting the middleman out entirely and using the [federated storage engine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/federated-usagenotes.html)--but that too would be a non-python approach.